# How to check if a list has the same elements as another list, being able to have duplicate

Tags: java, list, compare

I have 2 lists with different types of names of citys:

```
ArrayList<City> list1 = new ArrayList<City>();
ArrayList<City> list2 = new ArrayList<City>();


list1.add(Birmingham);
list1.add(Amsterdam);
list1.add(Rotterdam);
list1.add(Brussels);

list2.add(Brussels);
list2.add(Brussels);
list2.add(Rotterdam);
list2.add(Amsterdam);
list2.add(Amsterdam);
```

if i compare these 2 lists, it should be **true**

if i have a third list:

```
list3.add(brussELtss);
list3.add(Rotterdam);
list3.add(Amsterdam);
```

If i compare the third list to either of the first 2 it should be **false**

I tried comparing, equals and containsall, but that doesnt work.

Comment: How do you expect to get *true* when comparing list1 and list2 when they don't have the same elements?

Comment: maybe using a Map<City, Integer> where the integer is a counter.  first you'd check to see if the lists are the same size, if not immediately return false.  If they are you could loop through each list incrementing the counter for the first list and decrementing the counter for the second.  Then loop throught the Map to check if everything is zero for count. If the Map contains all zeros then they are equal, return true, else false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have [set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) for this, Have a look at [Hashset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) implementation which will containing the unique element. Your object City needs to implement Comparable/Comparator to decide on equality. Add first element in set and then start adding second list, if add method returns true then element is already there

**Update :-** After reading comment, i can think of below O(n) time complexity Algo

1. Iterate over first list and  construct a map(HashMap as implemetaion) with element as key and count as value
2. Iterate over second list, if element does not exist in map they are not equal.
3. If element found, reduce the count by one for that element in map
4. At last iterate over map, if there is an element with count other than zero, then list are not equal

Comment: No thats not what i meant, the lists CAN have duplicate entries, its only that when comparing them it should also be true